# Unable to get data from Google analytics with rga R library

Tags: r, google-analytics

I'm trying to use rga library but I'm getting this error:

```
Error in parseJSON(txt) : lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=en> 
                     (right here) ------^
```

This is my code:

```
rga.open()
profiles<-ga$getProfiles()
ids<-profiles[1]
data <- ga$getData(ids[1],
                   start.date = "2014-12-01", 
                   end.date = "2014-12-04",  
                   metrics = "ga:sessions",  
                   dimensions = "ga:date",
                   max = 1500,
                   sort="",
                   filters="")
```

I tested the query in
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/
and it's working

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rga](https://github.com/skardhamar/rga) package not maintained now. Please try `RGA` or `RGoogleAnalytics` from CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this was due to having a space in your ids[1]